# Showing an image on mouse over of text using jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script that will show an image when you mouse over certain words.  In a not visible part of the script, I query my database for all of those names and give them a span around the word. Like so: `<span>Word from my database</span>.`

However, the issue I run into is that the text takes on all of these css properties as well, so the words shift to the right/left.  I would like the text to not move, but still show the image when you mouse over those words.  If there was a jquery class to allow me to edit individual css classes, I think it would be an easy fix -- but I am all out of ideas.  I have also tried using the hover function in jquery, but I ran into similar issues.

My jquery code that simply looks for the span containing the names from my database, then applies those css styles on mouseover to the span and removes the styles on mouseout.

```
$( "span:contains('" + names + "')" ).mouseover( 
    function() {
        $(this).css("display", "inline");
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('" + link2 + "')");
        $(this).css("position", "absolute");
        $(this).css("width", "307");
        $(this).css("height", "465");
        $(this).css("z-index", "100");
    })

$( "span:contains('" + names + "')" ).mouseout( 
    function() {
        $(this).css("display", "");
        $(this).css("background-image", "");
        $(this).css("position", "");
        $(this).css("width", "");
        $(this).css("height", "");
        $(this).css("z-index", "");
    })
```

Comment: remove display inline attribute!

Comment: Unfortunately the text still shifts over with either inline, block or not being there at all.

Comment: Let me try to get this right. You want the css to be applied to the image but not the word? Then why not just applied the css to the `<img>` tag instead of `<span>`?

Comment: You should use html attributes for this, make it for example: `<span class="has_image" data-image="path_to_image.jpg">your_word</span>`, than append the `<img>` on `mouseenter`, remove on `mouseleave`. Everything else control with css, as `.has_image{position:relative}.has_image img{position:absolute}`

Comment: That's a good idea skobaljic, I will try to implement it.

@isim, only because there is no image until the user mouses over the text, it is being dynamically created and then placed in the background-image css tag

Comment: @user2793442 Then can you just hide the image, and reveal it only when `mouseover`? And re-hides it again on `mouseout`?